# Variable "$charactersID" of required type "ID!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am using apollo, graphql, react, mongo and trying to create a new user on the client side with just the name and email and have it posted on the homepage but I get this error when I hit the submit button - Variable "$charactersID" of required type "ID!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined. I have tried setting a variable for charactersID but not sure if I was doing it correctly

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Add_User} from '../gql/mutations'
import {Mutation} from 'react-apollo'

class Signup extends Component{
render(){
    let name, email;
    return(
      <Mutation mutation={Add_User} onCompleted={() => this.props.history.push('/')}>
          {(addUser, {loading, error}) => (
              <div>
                  Create new user
                <form onSubmit= {e=>{e.preventDefault(); 
                    addUser({variables: {name: name.value, email: email.value }})
                    name.value = ""
                    email.value = ""
                    }}>
                 <input type="text" name="name" ref={node => { name = node}} placeholder 
    ="NAME"/> 
                 <input type="text" name="email" ref={node => { email = node}} placeholder 
    ="EMAIL"/> 
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>

             {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
             {error && <p>Error : Please try again </p>}
              </div>

          )}
      </Mutation>
    )
}
}

export default Signup;
```

**Mutations**

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export const Add_User = gql`
mutation addUser($name: String!, $email: String, $description: String, $totalwins: Int, 
$charactersID: ID!){
addUser(name: $name, email: $email, description: $description, totalwins: $totalwins, 
charactersID: $charactersID){
    _id
    email
    name
    description
    totalwins
    charactersID{
        name  
        wins
        losses
        percentage
        image
    }
}
}
`
```

Comment: probably you don't need `charactersID` to create user object - you can assign/add/change nested/related data using separate mutations

Answer (score 0):

Your operation includes five variables:

```
$name: String!
$email: String
$description: String
$totalwins: Int
$charactersID: ID!
```

Only two of these are non-null, which means they are required -- `name` and `charactersID`. However, you're only providing `name` and `email` when calling the mutation function:

```
addUser({variables: {name: name.value, email: email.value }})
```

Comment: Ok I kinda figured that was the issue but that didnt address me wanting to create a user with only the name and email to be used for this specific component with the two input fields how would I go about doing that without having to have the charactersID included. I still need it for other uses but not for this now

Comment: If you make the variable nullable (`ID` instead of `ID!`), then GraphQL won't require it. In that case, you could also just omit both the variable and the argument altogether. However, if the argument's type is `ID!` in the schema, then it *has* to be provided -- in which case you'd need to change your schema first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I figured it out. My character model is nested in the user model so I took the non-nullable off and changed them to nullable fields on the character model. It wasn't the id itself just the field the character model contained and now it works as intended